# Problem with adding a custom field to existing view

Tags: view, module, odoo

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a problem with adding a new field to the sale order view of odoo12. I have created a new module. I hope that you can help me. 
Below the code of my view form

````
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml"></field>
                <field name="payment_term_id" position="after">
                        <field name="additional_note"/>
                </field>
</record>
</odoo>```

when i try to install the new module i have the following error:

File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3557, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 3


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1DOw.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `<field name="arch" type="xml"></field>` line: the `<field>` tag is closed, and your `additional_note` field is declared outside of it.

Try this code instead:

```
<odoo>

    <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <!-- Leave the 'arch' field open -->
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <!-- Put your custom field and its position inside the 'arch' field.
                 Use 'xpath' tag to create a more precise positioning -->
            <xpath expr="//group/group/field[@name='payment_term_id']" position="after">
                <field name="additional_note"/>
            </xpath>
        <!-- Now, close the 'arch' field -->
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

The view is not correctly defined, you can refer to [account_analytic_view](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/views/account_analytic_view.xml#L8).

The view definition should be (according to the provided link):

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <field name="payment_term_id" position="after">
                    <field name="additional_note"/>
                </field>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```